# Searching multiple elasticsearch's indexes using Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am able to search on elasticsearch's with one index, but i want to search on multiple indexes and sources.

Please find the below code which am using to search on one single `index` and one single `source`

```
private final String INDEX = "my_index";
private final String TYPE = "doc";
private final String SOURCE = "doct_name";

GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(INDEX, TYPE, SOURCE);
getRequest.routing(name);

GetResponse getResponse = null;

try {
    getResponse = restHighLevelClient.get(getRequest);
} catch (java.io.IOException e){
    e.getLocalizedMessage();
}
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
searchRequest.types(TYPE);

String star="*";
String query=star.concat(name).concat("*");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
QueryStringQueryBuilder qsQueryBuilder = new QueryStringQueryBuilder(query); 
qsQueryBuilder.defaultField("*");
searchSourceBuilder.query(qsQueryBuilder); 
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
try {
     searchResponse = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.getLocalizedMessage();
}
```

Comment: did you able to resolve this? Help me to solve the same

Answer (score 0):

Just use the varargs constructor of [SearchRequest](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.0.0/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequest.html#SearchRequest-java.lang.String...-) to pass multiple index names.

> Constructs a new search request against the indices. No indices
>   provided here means that search will run against all indices.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX, INDEX2)
```

Comment: Am getting the below error, when i pass 2 index in SearchRequest `java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal character in path at index 10: /my_index, documents_test2/doc/_search`

Answer (score 0):

You can [Searchrequest](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest) constructor with array indexes.

```
String indices[]-{INDEX, INDEX2}

this.searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indices);
```